# My "camera" is reversed when i get to a certain location in the z direction, what could be causing this?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, soil

I am Using c++, OpenGL, SOIL graphics library, and Microsoft Visual c++ 2010 Express.
i've added a video to demonstrate the problem
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7F7YDN0zbc4&feature=youtu.be

This is my current problem;

Our stage, or environment is a 3D[x][y][z].
The problem doesn't occur when we move in the x direction and neither on the y(we don't allow moving in the y direction in terms of steps, we can jump).
But once we get to z=70, the camera turns around. so if moving towards z=70 whilst x and y are 1, lets consider our facing + in the z direction, but once we reach 70, our camera turns around but our facing is still +. I know this because i have a cout << that tells me the direction and coordinate system position.

```
cout << "The player is at position: " << player.getXPos() << ", " << player.getYPos()  << ", " << player.getZPos() << ", " << player.getFacing() << "\n";
```

I am not sure what kind of code i need to put in here, so what kind of functions should i put in here.

//this is our starting position

```
void demo(){
     gameState = 1;
     player.setPos(4,1,15);
     player.setFacing(3);
     setPos();
     cout << "The player is at position: " << player.getXPos() << ", " << player.getYPos() << ", " << player.getZPos() << ", " << player.getFacing();
}
```

//this is how we set our position

```
void setPos(){
     currentXPos = player.getXPos()+(player.getXWidth()/2);
     currentYPos = player.getYPos()+(player.getYHeight());
     currentZPos = player.getZPos()+(player.getZDepth()/2); 
     currentYFace = currentYPos; 
     if(player.getFacing() == 0){
         currentXFace = MAPWIDTH;
         currentZFace = currentZPos;
     }else if(player.getFacing() == 2){
         currentXFace = 0;
         currentZFace = currentZPos;
     }else if(player.getFacing() == 3){
         currentXFace = currentXPos;
         currentZFace = MAPDEPTH;
     }else{
         currentXFace = currentXPos;
         currentZFace = 0;
     }
}
```

//this is our display function

```
 void /*GraphicsEngine::*/display(){
      glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
       glLoadIdentity ();
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
      glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
       glClearDepth(1.0);
      glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
      glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
      glLoadIdentity();
      setPos();
      gluLookAt(currentXPos,currentYPos,currentZPos,currentXFace,currentYFace,currentZFace,0,1,0);
      generateMap();
      graphicsFloor();
      int i = 0;
      if(projectiles.size()>0){
         for(i= 0; i< projectiles.size(); i++){
             arrow(projectiles.operator[](i).getXPos(),projectiles.operator[](i).getYPos(),projectiles.operator[](i).getZPos(),0.5,BLOCKWIDTH);
         }
         projectileMotion();
         player.advance();
         glutPostRedisplay();
      }else if(player.advance()){
          glutPostRedisplay();
      }
      glFlush();
      glutSwapBuffers();
 }
```

//this is our reshape function

```
void reshape(int w, int h){
        glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(60.0, (GLfloat) w/(GLfloat) h, 1.0, 200.0);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -3.6);
        glLoadIdentity();
}
```

//this is how we control what the user does with keyboard, i won't post all of the other cases since, they are blank

```
 void userAction(unsigned int userInput){
int i;
switch(userInput){
    case 1:
        player.turnLeft();
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 2:
        player.turnRight();
        //apply graphics
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 3:
        if(player.getFacing() == 0){
            player.setPos(player.getXPos()-1,player.getYPos(),player.getZPos());
            cout << "The player is at position: " << player.getXPos() << ", " << player.getYPos() << ", " << player.getZPos() << ", " << player.getFacing() << "\n";
        }else if(player.getFacing() ==3){
            player.setPos(player.getXPos(),player.getYPos(),player.getZPos()-1);
            cout << "The player is at position: " << player.getXPos() << ", " << player.getYPos() << ", " << player.getZPos() << ", " << player.getFacing() << "\n";
        }else if(player.getFacing() == 2){
            player.setPos(player.getXPos()+1,player.getYPos(),player.getZPos());
            cout << "The player is at position: " << player.getXPos() << ", " << player.getYPos() << ", " << player.getZPos() << ", " << player.getFacing() << "\n";
        }else{
            player.setPos(player.getXPos(),player.getYPos(),player.getZPos()+1);
            cout << "The player is at position: " << player.getXPos() << ", " << player.getYPos() << ", " << player.getZPos() << ", " << player.getFacing() << "\n";
        }
        //apply graphics
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 4:
        if(player.getFacing() == 0){
            player.setPos(player.getXPos()+1,player.getYPos(),player.getZPos());
            cout << "The player is at position: " << player.getXPos() << ", " << player.getYPos() << ", " << player.getZPos() << ", " << player.getFacing() << "\n";
        }else if(player.getFacing() ==3){
            player.setPos(player.getXPos(),player.getYPos(),player.getZPos()+1);
            cout << "The player is at position: " << player.getXPos() << ", " << player.getYPos() << ", " << player.getZPos() << ", " << player.getFacing() << "\n";
        }else if(player.getFacing() == 2){
            player.setPos(player.getXPos()-1,player.getYPos(),player.getZPos());
            cout << "The player is at position: " << player.getXPos() << ", " << player.getYPos() << ", " << player.getZPos() << ", " << player.getFacing() << "\n";
        }else{
            player.setPos(player.getXPos(),player.getYPos(),player.getZPos()-1);
            cout << "The player is at position: " << player.getXPos() << ", " << player.getYPos() << ", " << player.getZPos() << ", " << player.getFacing() << "\n";
        }
        //apply graphics
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 5:
        if(player.getFacing() == 0){
            player.setPos(player.getXPos(),player.getYPos(),player.getZPos()-1);
            cout << "The player is at position: " << player.getXPos() << ", " << player.getYPos() << ", " << player.getZPos() << ", " << player.getFacing() << "\n";
        }else if(player.getFacing() == 2){
            player.setPos(player.getXPos(),player.getYPos(),player.getZPos()+1);
            cout << "The player is at position: " << player.getXPos() << ", " << player.getYPos() << ", " << player.getZPos() << ", " << player.getFacing() << "\n";
        }else if(player.getFacing() == 3){
            player.setPos(player.getXPos()+1,player.getYPos(),player.getZPos());
            cout << "The player is at position: " << player.getXPos() << ", " << player.getYPos() << ", " << player.getZPos() << ", " << player.getFacing() << "\n";
        }else{
            player.setPos(player.getXPos()-1,player.getYPos(),player.getZPos());
            cout << "The player is at position: " << player.getXPos() << ", " << player.getYPos() << ", " << player.getZPos() << ", " << player.getFacing() << "\n";
        }
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 6:
        if(player.getFacing() == 0){
            player.setPos(player.getXPos(),player.getYPos(),player.getZPos()+1);
            cout << "The player is at position: " << player.getXPos() << ", " << player.getYPos() << ", " << player.getZPos() << ", " << player.getFacing() << "\n";
        }else if(player.getFacing() == 2){
            player.setPos(player.getXPos(),player.getYPos(),player.getZPos()-1);
            cout << "The player is at position: " << player.getXPos() << ", " << player.getYPos() << ", " << player.getZPos() << ", " <<player.getFacing() << "\n";
        }else if(player.getFacing() == 1){
            player.setPos(player.getXPos()+1,player.getYPos(),player.getZPos());
            cout << "The player is at position: " << player.getXPos() << ", " << player.getYPos() << ", " << player.getZPos() << ", " << player.getFacing() << "\n";
        }else{
            player.setPos(player.getXPos()-1,player.getYPos(),player.getZPos());
            cout << "The player is at position: " << player.getXPos() << ", " << player.getYPos() << ", " << player.getZPos() << ", " << player.getFacing() << "\n";
        }
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
 }
```

//and this is how we set the face

```
 void PlayerCharacter::setFacing(unsigned short newFace){
      facing = newFace % 4;
 }
```

//and this is for the position

```
bool PlayerCharacter::setPos(int x, int y, int z){
positionData pTemp;
pTemp.x = x;
pTemp.y = y;
pTemp.z = z;
pTemp.id = p.id;
pTemp.w = p.w;
pTemp.h = p.h;
pTemp.d = p.d;
pTemp.type = p.type;
 if(/*phys->*/openBlocks(pTemp) && /*phys->*/validPosition(pTemp)==0){
      p.x=x;
      p.y=y;
      p.z=z;
      /*phys->*/updatePlacements(p);
      return true;
 }else{
      return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: Show the code that modifies the camera, please.

Comment: i believe that is all the code for how the camera works

Comment: i've added a video, showing what i mean.

Comment: Presumably the view position is passing the view target, causing it to turn around. It's tricky to tell because there is so much cruft in the code - the number of redundant matrix operations is confusing, you clear the screen multiple times for no apparent reason, and you're posting a display request from the display function itself... it's confusing to read.

Comment: okay, I've deleted some of the redundant redisplay functions, game still works.

Comment: What is the value of `MAPDEPTH`?  I would suspect that `currentZPos` is crossing it.

Comment: You are right, currentZPos = player.getZPos()+(player.getZDepth()/2); if i increase the division, the point at which i reverse gets longer, let me see which number is the magic number.

Comment: so, any number past 35, i turn at 104, but until a certain point, i tried out division by 999 and i didn't turn. you solved my problem, thank you so much.

Comment: i also, commented it out and its now  currentZPos = player.getZPos(); and i don't need to do any division, and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currentZPos = player.getZPos(); Doing this fixes the problem